# How to re-key array with non-sequential numeric keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
Array
(
 [0] => ololo
 [2] => test
 [3] => haha
 [7] => nice
)
```

How can I change the indexes of the array to this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => ololo
 [1] => test
 [2] => haha
 [3] => nice
)
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From PHP.net:

> array_values() returns all the values from the input array and indexes the array  numerically.

[Source](http://php.net/array_values)

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

Answer (score 7):

array_values() is probably what you want.  See: http://php.net/function.array-values

```
$myArray = array_values($myArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

This will re-index the array keys:

```
array_values($array)
```

Answer (score 2):

[array_values()](http://us.php.net/array_values)

Answer (score 2):

If you have your initial array within `$a` variable, you can just do the following:

```
$a = array_values($a);
```

Which will basically return values from within your original array, and will do it in the another array.

Is it clear enough?